# Adding Column value from first row to the current row

Tags: sql-server

Suppose we have a `table A`,

```
x   y

1   2
2   3
3   5
4   6
5   9
6   10
```

Write a query which sums up like below

```
table b

x   y
1   2
2   5
3   10
4   16
5   25
6   35
```

The above problem is to be solved without using Loops.

Comment: `mysql` or `SQL-Server`?

Comment: Could you please also share with us the query you have tried so far?

Comment: I am more interested in sql server

Answer (score 2):

use sum() over () clause

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([x] int, [y] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([x], [y])
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 5),
    (4, 6),
    (5, 9),
    (6, 10)
;
;
select x, sum(y) over (order by x) as y from #table1
```

Comment: Thanks Chanukya,This worked for me

Comment: @user3578800, so please mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set @count:=0;
Select x,@count:=@count+y from tablename ORDER BY x;
```

Try above query.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Strawberry yes i had updated my answer. Thank You..!! _/\_